# Getting TIBCO EMS Queue

Tags: java, tibco, ems

i try to create class java can acess to EMS queue check pending msg 
but it's give me error in line `TibjmsAdmin admin = new TibjmsAdmin("tcp://local host:7222","admin","");`
below my simple code

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws TibjmsAdminException {
    TibjmsAdmin admin = new TibjmsAdmin("tcp://localhost:7222","admin","");
    String destName = null;
    QueueInfo di = admin.getQueue("test");
    StatData iStats = di.getInboundStatistics();
    StatData oStats = di.getOutboundStatistics();
    long pendingMessages = di.getPendingMessageCount();
    long pendingSize = di.getPendingMessageSize();
    long inMsgRate = iStats.getMessageRate();
    long inByteRate = iStats.getByteRate();
    long outMsgRate = oStats.getMessageRate();
    long outByteRate = oStats.getByteRate();
    System.out.println(pendingMessages);
}
```

what i try do method can give him queue name it's give me pending Msg

> Error :
>   run:
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/tibco/tibjms/TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory
>       at com.tibco.tibjms.admin.MessengerUtil.(MessengerUtil.java:46)
>       at com.tibco.tibjms.admin.TibjmsAdmin.(TibjmsAdmin.java:424)
>       at com.tibco.tibjms.admin.TibjmsAdmin.(TibjmsAdmin.java:405)
>       at EMS.main(EMS.java:31)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       ... 4 more
>   Java Result: 1
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the tibjms.jar file into your class path

```
java -cp &lt;path to jar&gt;/tibjms.jar:<all my other jars>
```

Comment: /tibjms.jar may be unlikely location. Did you forget to add "." before "/tibjms.jar"

Comment: What Mike means is you need to add java dependencies to make your code work. In java dependecies comes as jar file and java looks for dependecies in CLASSPATH. You need to set that jar in your JVM's CLASSPATH.Refer : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: @Jayan Put the path to jar in originally, but forgot this is html...  All fixed now.